# Non-responsive textboxes in Chrome for mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Have a B2B website written in ASP.NET MVC, doing browser compatibility checks and found this. The Registration screen has a large collection of textboxes for accepting data, these have to be filled and submitted to move on. But the textboxes are simply not accepting any data! Clicking on them does nothing, trying to type into them does nothing. It all works fine on other (Windows) browsers and Safari. There's nothing unusual showing in the DOM, the <input type="text"...> tags aren't read-only or disabled, it's a very simple scenario, just not used to the Mac. Any ideas? I have been googling all morning and found nothing. The only thing I can think of is that the version of Bootstrap we are using is 3.0.0 but the docs claims it is compatible with Mac Chrome (though obviously that was a while ago...).